# Form preview before submission

Tags: forms

I have written a form using the form API, and I want the user to preview the form before submission. How can this be accomplished?

Comment: The Node module provides an example on how to do it, but in general it's not that easy.

Comment: Can you elaborate a little bit more about your use case? What kind of data is the user entering? Do you have authenticated or anonymous users?

Answer (score 1):

Effectively this is a multistep form. Display the form showing a "Preview" button. On submit save something to the session or $form_state and redisplay the form. If the value has been set in the session show a "Submit" button. On this submit you can save the form values to the database and clear whatever flag value you had in the database.